# Typescript definitions for nested package exports

Tags: node.js, typescript

**Goal:**
I'm trying to build a UI-Kit that can be consumed by web applications and react native applications. I have a specific need to be able to do this without react-native-web.

**My Solution:**
Create a UI Kit that has a shared interface layer. I have a project that exports two nested folders. `@abc/ui-kit/web` and `@abc/ui-kit/native`

**My Problem:**
When I import the UI Kit package, Typescript complains about a missing module definition.

```
import { Button } from '@abc/ui-kit';
import { Button } from '@abc/ui-kit/web';
```

> Cannot find module '@abc/ui-kit' or its corresponding type
> declarations

> Cannot find module '@abc/ui-kit/web' or its corresponding
> type declarations

My package.json for the UI-Kit has the following exports:

```
"exports": {
    "web": {
      "types": "./dist/web/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/web/index.ts"
    },
    "native": {
      "types": "./dist/native/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/native/index.ts"
    }
  }
```

You can find the code here on Github. Easy to recreate, I tried keeping it minimal. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Or do I need to completely restructure my application?

https://github.com/Spidy88/multi-platform-example/tree/master

Note: If you look under the dev branch, I have a v1 UI Kit and App which shows how a regular library and consuming app work. No issues with it. The v2 UI Kit and App are my next iteration where I try and turn a single package into a multiple platform package (which essentially is two packages in one using package.json exports). This v2 version is what doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Subpaths must start with `./` (answered by a colleague) [Subpath Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports)

```
"exports": {
    "./web": {
      "types": "./dist/web/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/web/index.ts"
    },
    "./native": {
      "types": "./dist/native/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/native/index.ts"
    }
  }
```